# нейронная сеть плохо предсказывает результат по данным не входящим в обучающую выборку

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети

нейронная сетка на основе этого https://github.com/encog/encog-javascript

если учить так

```
XOR_INPUT = [ [0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]]; //(x*x+x)[1,1,1],
XOR_IDEAL = [ [0],    [1],     [0],    [1]  ,  [0]  , [1],    [1] ];//[1],
```

то по вопросу 1 1 1 ответ 1

а если учить так

```
XOR_INPUT = [ [0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]; //(x*x+x)[1,1,0],
XOR_IDEAL = [ [0],    [1],     [0],    [1]  ,  [0]  , [1],    [1] ];//[1],
```

по вопросу 1 1 0 ответ почему то 0

Comment: а почему Вы решили, что Ваш ответ единственно верный, и нет такой функции, которая бы при 110 давала бы 0?

Comment: а как тогда поступить?

Comment: Для сети нужно больше выборку. Сильно больше.

Comment: Это ещё актуально?